# How do you delete the Mindfulness app on Vision Pro?

Tags: visionos

How do you delete the Mindfulness app on Vision Pro?

Comment: What steps have you tried already?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Apple Insider](https://appleinsider.com/articles/24/02/04/how-to-delete-apps-from-the-apple-vision-pro):

> By default, you can delete any third-party app you install to the Apple Vision Pro from the App Store.
>
> **Most of the apps built into visionOS cannot be deleted**, but Apple does make an exception for two of them. You do have the option to delete Keynote from the Apple Vision Pro, as well as Encounter Dinosaurs.